# Python socket.recv hanging

Tags: python, networking, plc

I'm trying to retrieve data from a PLC (AutomationDirect P2000). I have set up the PLC as the server with their software program (I can also connect to it with their software via Ethernet and use Wireshark to see it is in fact sending UDP packets to my machine at roughly every 200ms). I am trying to set up a very simple Python script to retrieve said data, without bothering to encode it or do anything with it, but my program hangs at the socket.recv(). Whenever I try to run it "Got here" will be printed, but "Now here" will not. From what I've read the fact that it hangs means there's no data to be received, but from my (limited) understanding of what I see on Wireshark this is not the case. I am pretty new to all of this and would appreciate any help.

I have tried using socket.recvfrom(), which produces the same result. I've also tried using socket.bind() instead of socket.connect() but I get a "The requested address is not valid in its context" exception. Additionally, I've tried playing around with various IPs and ports. For example, I've tried using IP = '' instead of the actual IP, and I've tried the source/destination information from Wireshark as what I try to bind or connect to, but nothing thus far has worked.

```
import socket

IP = '192.168.3.1'
PORT = 9999
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect((IP, PORT))

while True:
    print("Got here")
    data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    print("Now here")
    print(f"Received {data}")
```

I am expecting to get a print out of the packet in byte format, but instead the program is hanging. If I try socket.bind() instead of socket.connect() I get an error message reading "...line 8, in 
    s.bind((IP, PORT))

OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context"

Comment: This might be helpful!! Refer https://github.com/KiranMayeeMaddi/ReliableFileTransferOverUDP/blob/master/GoBackNARQ/Server/server.py

Answer (score 0):

you can't use `bind` like this, because the ip address does not belong to your PC.

when you `connect` to the server, it (the server) doesn't send anything, but you try to get data from the server, so the socket awaits until it gets data, and only then it will continue the execution (this is called a blocking function, since it blocks the execution until it finishes).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yeah I tested it with a non-blocking socket and it throws an error (presumably because there is no data). If this is the case and there is no data, why am I seeing data from the IP of the PLC going to the IP of my machine using Wireshark?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is Firewall blocking data to the socket

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with how I set up the PLC as the server. The UDP data I was seeing on port 9999 wasn't the communications I was thinking it was, and was only the inherent communication between the PLC and the network via its proprietary program. For anyone curious, I am using a P2000 PLC from AutomationDirect and initially I set it up as an EtherNet/IP Adapter following one of their videos, but I had to use the Custom Protocol over Ethernet functionality provided in the "Communications" section.